# CodeBlocks will not stop at the breakpoint

Tags: debugging, codeblocks, breakpoints

I synaptic codeblocks on my PCLinux OS.
In the terminal, "su -"
entered root's password
In the terminal, "codeblocks"
Created a project from the template, "console" -Hello World.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Two targets" Debug  and release.

### I build debug.

-------------- Build: Debug in consolesimple (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -Wall -pg -g -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -c /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/consolesimple obj/Debug/main.o  -pg
Output file is bin/Debug/consolesimple with size 20.87 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

---

I set the breakpoint at cout line.

I press F8, debug start.  But the debugger did not stop.

## debug window:

Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/
Adding source dir: /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/
Adding file: /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/bin/Debug/consolesimple
Changing directory to: /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/.
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
Starting debugger: /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/bin/Debug/consolesimple -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args /root/Documents/CodeBlocksSpace/consolesimple/bin/Debug/consolesimple
done

## Debugger finished with status 0

Can anybody help me why the debugger never stop at the breakpoint?

thanks.